# How to configure ctags to better choose the definition file for the tag under the cursor

Tags: python, git, vim, wagtail, ctags

Here's an example using a python file:

[image]

On top of the `Page` import from the `wagtail.core.models` module, when pressing `C-]` within vim, I get prompted to choose between 13 options.

**I shouldn't be prompted for it, and there's only one page matching the import line in question: the 3rd tag (`...site-packages/wagtail/core/models.py`)**

It is strange why ctags doesn't handle this correctly by default, but so be it. I would like to fix the configuration, but after spending two days on it, I'm a bit lost. Any help appreciated.

```
$ uname -a
Linux xps9360 5.0.7-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr 8 10:37:08 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ pacman -Qs ctags
local/universal-ctags-git 0.r6117.c45511a3-1
    Multilanguage reimplementation of the Unix ctags utility
$ tree ~/.git_template  # http://tbaggery.com/2011/08/08/effortless-ctags-with-git.html
/home/dori/.git_template
└── hooks
    ├── ctags
    ├── post-checkout
    ├── post-commit
    ├── post-merge
    └── post-rewrite
$ git ctags
```

`.git/hooks/ctags` (from [this blog](https://www.fusionbox.com/blog/detail/navigating-your-django-project-with-vim-and-ctags/590/))

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e
PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
dir="`git rev-parse --git-dir`"
trap 'rm -f "$dir/$$.tags"' EXIT
git ls-files | \
    #ctags --tag-relative -L - -f"$dir/$$.tags" --languages=-javascript,sql
    ctags -R --fields=+l --languages=python --python-kinds=-iv -f"$dir/$$.tags" $(python -c "import os, sys; print(' '.join('{}'.format(d) for d in sys.path if os.path.isdir(d)))")
```

extract from `~/.vimrc`:

```
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive' 
Plug 'jsfaint/gen_tags.vim'
autocmd User GenTags#CtagsLoaded echo "Ctags are loaded!"
"let g:gen_tags#ctags_opts = '–python-kinds=-i --verbose'
let g:gen_tags#statusline = 1
let g:gen_tags#verbose = 1
```

In the current example, I'm starting a project using the WagTail django-base framework, which I'm not familiar with, and need to regularly check the file definitions to better understand what's happening under the hood.
I wish I could have a pleasant experience to improve my productivity.

EDIT Django templates:

Ctags doesn't seem to support [django templates](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/languages.html). Triggering C-] on top of an extend returns garbage tags. My current process is to `:CtrlP path/to/wagtaildir/`, then search for the name of the template my file is extending from

[image]

This is far from optimal. I'd love to hear any improvement suggestions on this method.